# How to bind more than 1 property to element?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm playing around with knockout and I can't figure out how do I bind more than 1 object property to an element?

This is my template and I tried `data-bind="text: name.first name.last"`:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name.first name.last"></h3>
    <p>Age: <span data-bind="text: age"></span></p>
    <p>Company: <span data-bind="text: company"></span></p>
    <hr>
</script>
```

In angular I'd use ng-repeat and do something like `<h3>{{name.first}} {{name.last}}</h3>`but I don't want to load angular for this project

Comment: You don't, not like that anyway. You're binding a _value_, so you must combine your properties to a single value. Either inline or preferredly, as a computed property.

Comment: What Jeff said, or introduce extra html elements `<h3><span data-bind="text: name.first"></span> <span data-bind="text: name.last"></span></h3>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```html
<h3 data-bind="text: name.first + ' ' + name.last"></h3>
```

or this, if those items are observables:

```html
<h3 data-bind="text: name.first() + ' ' + name.last()"></h3>
```

or this, if you want to keep things seperate in your view:

```html
<h3 data-bind="with: name">
  <span data-bind="text: first"></span>
  <span data-bind="text: last"></span>
</h3>
```

or this, if you want to mimick Angular as close as possible:

```html
<h3>
  <!-- ko text: name.first --><!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko text: name.last --><!-- /ko -->
</h3>
```

or this, if you want to unit test / make it into business logic:

```html
<h3 data-bind="text: name.fullname"></h3>
```

```
function Name() {
  var self = this;
  self.first = ko.observable();
  self.last = ko.observable();
  self.fullname = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.first() + " " + self.last();
  });
}
```

---

As a footnote, some relevant differences between KnockoutJS and AngularJS:

- In Knockout there is (without plugins) no direct equivalent of the AngularJS bracket style (e.g. `{{ name.first}}`) rendering.
- In KnockoutJS observable properties are functions (whereas Angular can track changes to plain JS properties). You can only (optionally) leave off parentheses if it's the *only* thing you're binding to. So supposing `first` is an observable, these work:

  ```html
  <span data-bind="text: name.first"></span> shortcut...
  <span data-bind="text: name.first()"></span> equivalent to previous...
  <span data-bind="text: name.first() + name.last()"></span> () are required now...
  ```

  but this doesn't:

  ```html
  <span data-bind="text: name.first + 'something else'"></span> !doesn't work!
  ```